# Continue numbering in custom list

Tags: microsoft-word, list

I have a macro to create a custom list. The list is of the Spanish ordinals in feminine. This is the code:

```
Sub ListaFemenino ()
Dim arrNumbers As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range
arrNumbers = Split ("Primera Segunda Tercera Cuarta Quinta Sexta Séptima Octava Novena")
Set rng = Selection.Range
For i = 1 To rng.Paragraphs.Count
     With rng.Paragraphs (i) .Range
         .Text = arrNumbers (i - 1) & vbTab & .FormattedText
         .ParagraphFormat.TabHangingIndent 2
     End With
Next i
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I need, if possible, that you give me the option, every time I want to apply it in the same document to continue the list or to restart it from 1, *Primera* in this case.

Actually what I need is for it to offer me the option to **continue the numbering** because restarting it from 1 is what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/optional-parameters

```
' 1 as default value if nothing is given as parameter
Sub ListaFemenino (s as long = 1) 

...
For i = s To rng.Paragraphs.Count
...
```

... with this you then need to detect from where to continue, how that is to be done is dependent on where you use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, David:
Could I use a certain style, which could also be called ListaFemenino, so that it detects where to proceed?
So that every time I apply that style (ListaFemenino) and press the macro button, it is applied to the selected paragraphs, continuing the numbering from where it left off the previous time.

What would the code look like in this case?

Comment: Can someone help me with the code to only number the paragraphs with a certain style (FemaleList) even if they are not consecutive

Comment: Dim arrNumbers As Variant 

Dim i As Long, j As Long 

Dim rng As Range 

arrNumbers = Split("Primera Segunda Tercera Cuarta Quinta Sexta Séptima Octava Novena") 

Set rng = Selection.Range 

j = 1 

For i = 1 To rng.Paragraphs.Count 

    If rng.Paragraphs(i).Style = "ListaFemenino" Then 

        With rng.Paragraphs(i).Range 

            .Text = arrNumbers(j - 1) & vbTab & .FormattedText 

            .ParagraphFormat.TabHangingIndent 2 

            j = j + 1 

        End With 

    End If 

Next i

Comment: Hello again:
I am trying with this new code but it does not work either.